# Does using enums instead of booleans really affect cache usage?

Tags: performance, caching, enums

I saw a comment thread where it was suggested that enums should be used instead of booleans in general since it's clearer what the parameters do at the call site, and it's easier to refactor if you need to add a case.

Then someone else claimed that that was a terrible idea since it would often create an unnecessary variable for each call, which would be an unnecessary use of compute resources and cache space.

Does this second claim hold up? My understanding is that booleans are usually not stored as single bits, but as sets of bits with more than enough room for the amount of extra options in a typical enum. So the same amount of data would need to be moved around.

If I understand correctly, there would be an extra variable required if the enum has 3 or more options, (one to store the enum and one for a derived boolean on each check,) but in that case, you actually needed the three options so what can you do? In the case that you have exactly two enum options, then couldn't a compiler just transform it into a boolean in the same register, (assuming the enum value was specified as not having one 0 value and one non-zero value,) therefore not using any extra space?

One extra compare instruction I suppose, but cache usage seems to be the much bigger deal performance-wise these days. And if you have an enum that's isomorphic to a boolean, you'll often make the values automatic anyway, so the compiler should be free to fully optimize it.

Do I understand this correctly, or am I missing something?

Comment: I got curious enough about what Rust does for multiple enums vs booleans that I made entered some code into [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/xMDapg) to see what assembly would be generated. I'm not great at reading assembly but the enums seem to have been compiled to a lookup table while the booleans were not. I'm not sure which would be faster, but there are some differences at least with a "young" compiler like Rust's.